# Mysql IF statement return issues

Tags: mysql

I have this query where the IF lines are only partially returning correct result:

SELECT

```
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM USERS_BUCKETS WHERE USERS_BUCKETS.USERID = USERS.ID),0) AS ADDED,
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN USERS_BUCKETS.STATUS='Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM USERS_BUCKETS WHERE USERS_BUCKETS.USERID = USERS.ID),0) AS DONE,
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM USERS_LIKES WHERE USERS_LIKES.USERID = USERS.ID),0) AS NUM_LIKES,
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW.USER_ID=USERS.ID),0) AS FOLLOWING,
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID=USERS.ID),0) AS FOLLOWERS,

(SELECT IF(ADDED >= 5,1,0)) AS IFADDED,
(SELECT IF(DONE >= 3,1,0)) AS IFDONE,
(SELECT IF(NUM_LIKES >= 5,1,0)) AS IFNUM_LIKES,
(SELECT IF(FOLLOWING >= 5,1,0)) AS IFFOLLOWING,
(SELECT IF(FOLLOWERS >= 3,1,0)) AS IFFOLLOWERS,

(SELECT IF(ADDED >= 5,1,0) + IF(DONE >= 3,1,0) + IF(NUM_LIKES >= 5,1,0) + IF(FOLLOWING >= 5,1,0) + IF(FOLLOWERS >= 3,1,0)) AS PROGRESS

FROM USERS 
WHERE USERS.ID=?
```

Result:

```
ADDED: 20
IFADDED: 1

DONE: 9
IFDONE: 0  //should be 1

NUM_LIKES: 11
IFNUM_LIKES: 1

FOLLOWING: 11
IFFOLLOWING: 0 //should be 1

FOLLOWERS: 10
IFFOLLOWERS: 0 //should be 1

PROGRESS: 2
```

What's wrong? All IF values should be 1 and PROGRESS should be 5.
Note: I am using PDO in php, but I don't think that matters at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why your code is working.  The columns are definitely not the column aliases defined earlier in the query.

To do what you want, use a subquery and simplify the logic:

```
SELECT u.*, (ADDED >= 5) AS IFADDED,
       (DONE >= 3) AS IFDONE,
       (NUM_LIKES >= 5) AS IFNUM_LIKES,
       (FOLLOWING >= 5) AS IFFOLLOWING,
       (FOLLOWERS >= 3) AS IFFOLLOWERS,
       ((ADDED >= 5) + (DONE >= 3) + (NUM_LIKES >= 5) + (FOLLOWING >= 5) + 
        (FOLLOWERS >= 3)
       ) AS PROGRESS  
FROM (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM USERS_BUCKETS WHERE USERS_BUCKETS.USERID = USERS.ID),0) AS ADDED,
             COALESCE((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN USERS_BUCKETS.STATUS='Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM USERS_BUCKETS WHERE USERS_BUCKETS.USERID = USERS.ID),0) AS DONE,
             COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM USERS_LIKES WHERE USERS_LIKES.USERID = USERS.ID),0) AS NUM_LIKES,
             COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW.USER_ID=USERS.ID),0) AS FOLLOWING,
             COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID=USERS.ID),0) AS FOLLOWERS
      FROM USERS 
      WHERE USERS.ID = ?
     ) u;
```

This takes advantage of the fact that MySQL treats booleans as integers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

EDIT:  I should also note that the `coalesce()` is unnecessary because `count()` will return `0` when there are no matches.

Comment: What do you mean by 'The columns are definitely not the column aliases defined earlier in the query'?

Comment: @endomester . . . You cannot refer to a column alias in the same `select` where it is defined.  That means that the columns in the `if()` expressions are recognized as columns in `users`; they do not refer to the values defined earlier in the `select`.

Comment: Thanks. Your code is working, but can you elaborate the big inner FROM part and what is `u` for?

Comment: @erdomester . . . That is a subquery -- which is pretty much what makes SQL a powerful language for data processing.  The `u` is a table aliases which is needed for subqueries, and in certain other circumstances.

Comment: Thanks. I am used to easier codes but will look into this.